# Solving a collective version of the vehicle routing problem

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra

I'm having troubles with finding an algorithm for the following problem:

In an undirected weighted graph with weights w there needs to be one package delivered from s to t. All nodes of the graph count as station. Each station has a specific type of vehicles with a given speed v and a traveling distance d. The vehicles need to work collective to deliver the package. So if a vehicle of current traveling distance 10 travels along an edge of weight 4, the traveling distance will be shortened to 6. Vehicles have to stop at a station, if they can't travel along a whole edge. The package can be handed over at any station.

I have to find the fastest possible path (by optimizing distance / speed)to deliver the package from s to t .

I've been looking through a lot of scientific papers with many versions of the vehicle routing problem, but it can't find one that deals with my problem.

I tried solving this with a modified version of djikstra by using edgeweights of w/v, but I don't know, when to mark a node as visited. I would be happy if someone has an idea for an algorithm how to solve the problem.

Comment: The edge weight w of (r,s) is the distance from r to s. The vehicle with speed v needs w/v time to travel from r to s. The time needs to be optimized.

Comment: What could really bake our noodle is if more than one vehicle is allowed to drive at the same time (like in real life).

Comment: Why? It's only one package that needs to be transported.

Comment: Say we need to deliver from A to D, and B is the only node leading to D. At node A we have a car that drives 10 miles an hour and can get to B in half an hour. At node C that's 500 miles from B, we have a car that drives 1000 miles an hour and can get to B in half an hour. We start both cars at the same time, meet at B and deliver the car to D in the faster car.

Comment: Only the car transporting the package is allowed to drive.

Answer (score 2):

I would codify a "state" as

- node `n` with the package
- time at which it arrived there
- speed & range of car that you used to get there

The starting state is package at `s`, time 0, car from `s` with full range. To find successor states to a given state, you would follow this logic:

- for each `e`, an outgoing edge from `n`; and only if the current car's range is sufficient, create 2 new successor states, `n1` and `n2`, with

```
node[n1] = node[n2] = target[e]
time[n1] = time[n2] = time[n] + length[e] / car_speed[n]
car_speed[n1] = car_speed[n]
car_range[n1] = car_range[n] - length[e]
car_speed[n2] = target[e].car_speed
car_range[n2] = target[e].car_range
```

You then use A* on this, using `time` as cost and a suitable heuristic, and find the optimal route & time at the end. Since I am unsure of the best heuristic here (time is distance/speed, but speed varies by car...), you may use a null heuristic, which may expand more nodes than usual, but will never overestimate.

The idea is that there are two ways to proceed from each node that you reach: switch the car or keep the one you arrived on. Since you don't know what the best decision is, you test both and see which works out better.

Memory-wise, assuming that you are only interested in the minimum time to reach the goal, and that your chosen heuristic is either null or both admissible and consistent, you only need to keep at most `2*V` open states for a graph with `V` nodes -- as already-visited nodes will never need to be visited again (mark them somewhere to avoid re-processing them if reached again), and old states can therefore be discarded with no ill effects.

[in the previous version, I was mixing up cost and heuristic; I have edited to clarify that I recommend a  null heuristic and time-as-cost]

Comment: So basically you create a new graph with a lot more nodes and edges?

Comment: Not really, because you are creating those states on the fly. The total number of states generated would be the total of different ways that you can arrive at each node; but it makes no sense to explore most of them, because you already got there earlier.

Comment: Do we keep both states in mind and return to the point, where we chose to expand one of the states, if the range of the current car and the cars in the current stations isn't enough to go to the next station, because a previous(and slower) car needed to be used to success further?

Comment: Imagine a straight line, where the first car has unlimited range and speed 1. All other cars have speed 2 and range 1. All edges but the first and the second have length 2.
The first and second edge have length 1. 
Optimal solution(and only working one) would be using the first car. Wouldn't the algorithm need to jump back to previous stations and try out other states?
So it needs to be a modified version of A*, right?

Comment: [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) uses a priority queue to choose state expansion order. It will visit new states (from "already visited" nodes; but note that each state, as defined above would only be visited at most once). This is not a "modified A*" except in the sense that states, their expansion, and the heuristic (time-from-origin) is problem-specific; but it is otherwise plain old A*

Comment: Why is time the preferred heuristic? We aren't guaranteed any of the states that have better time so far will be the final winners. We can, though, definitely say that states that dominate both speed and distance, given equal time, are favourites.

Comment: I have not given much thought to heuristic tie-breakers. Time seems safe, as expanding states that are reached sooner must lead to reaching the goal at the earliest possible time (and thus an optimal answer). I can picture bad answers being reached with other heuristics if, for example, there is a very fast&long-range car available far outside the direct path from start to goal.

Comment: Sorry if it sounds dumb, but am I right, that we are only using time as costs then? You mentioned using it as heuristic. A* calculates cost depending on the edgeweight+heuristic but are we just comparing the times? In compare to the default A* I don't need to save already visited nodes/states, right?

Comment: Updated to clarify that yes, I am proposing time as cost, and no heuristic at all. Sorry for the confusion on my part.

Comment: On your updated version : If we don't visit already visited nodes, we might not find the solution. A quick example: Edges with length: (a,b) - 1, (a,c) - 2, (b,d) - 3, (c,b) -1. Speed,Range of Nodes: a:(2,2),b:(1,1), c(1,4). We want to find a path from a to d. The algorithm will create the states (a,b) with time 0,5 and range 1 and (a,c) with time 1 and range 0. Since (a,b) has less time the algorithm will visit b. Because we don't have enough range, we can't expand further. So we will take a look at c. Here we can only expand (c,b) with a vehicle from c, but we already visited b.

Comment: So we can't mark b as visited, once we expanded notes from there. It's the range that sometimes leads to taking a path with worse time to a node, so we can expand further.
Without marking, we pretty much run through all possible combinations of paths in the worst case, aren't we? That's what I meant in a previous comment with not using default A*.
EDIT: We could at least throw away states, that lead to worse times and less or equal restrange.